# Create Azure SQL Analytics via Powershell

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I'm wondering if there is a specific Powershell command to create [Azure SQL Analytics](https://azuremarketplace.microsoft.com/en-au/marketplace/apps/Microsoft.AzureSQLAnalyticsOMS?tab=Overview) resource. So far I've only found [how to enable sending diagnostics logs to a Log Analytics workspace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-metrics-diag-logging).

I assume I can try arm template, but it will be nice if there is a dedicated command to avoid creating another json template.

Comment: can you specify what you want to create exactly? show a screenshot or, preferably, resource definition

Comment: @4c74356b41 I've described it in the question- it's Azure SQL Analytics. I'll make it as a link to be more clear

Comment: you just need to add this solution to azure monitor (or whatever its called now)?

Comment: @4c74356b41 to a Log Analytics workspace. And I want to automate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following powershell:

```
Set-AzOperationalInsightsIntelligencePack -ResourceGroupName rgName -WorkspaceName workspaceName -IntelligencePackName AzureSQLAnalytics -Enabled $true
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/powershell-workspace-configuration#create-and-configure-a-log-analytics-workspace